# Problems with running Android studio emulator on Mac OS X

Tags: android, macos, android-studio

I  successfully installed Android Studio on my Macbook Pro 8 Go memory under OS X El Capitan.I created a simple Hello World app and
then I tried to run the app, I was asked to create an AVD and chose Nexus 5 x config with x86. The device was created after downloading the image file and I ran the App. The Gradle process ran well and the app launched the emulator

I got the following message in the app window :

```
Error while waiting for device: Timed out after 300seconds waiting for emulator to come online.
```

The emulator showed only the word **"Android"**.
The emulator has been running for a **long time** (more than 30 mn)

Below you'll find  a very small extract of the emulator error window.

> 08-07 16:15:31.053 1203-1203/? E/perfprofd: unable to open
>   configuration file
>   /data/data/com.google.android.gms/files/perfprofd.conf 08-07
>   16:15:31.581 1198-1198/? E/cutils: Failed to read
>   /data/.layout_version: No such file or directory 08-07 16:15:34.368
>   1187-1187/? E/libEGL:
>   load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed:
>   library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found 08-07
>   16:15:34.967 1187-1187/? E/SurfaceFlinger: hwcomposer module not found
>   08-07 16:15:35.401 1187-1187/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace
>   file: Permission denied (13)

```
                                           --------- beginning of system
```

> 08-07 16:15:44.198 1197-1197/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace
>   file: Permission denied (13) 08-07 16:15:44.198 1197-1197/?
>   E/CameraService: setUpVendorTags: Vendor tag operations not fully
>   defined. Ignoring definitions. 08-07 16:15:46.354 1187-1219/?
>   E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build
>   property 08-07 16:15:46.428 1228-1304/? E/libEGL:
>   load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed:
>   library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found 08-07
>   16:15:46.673 1228-1304/? E/cutils-trace: Error opening trace file:
>   Permission denied (13)

```
                                           [ 08-07 16:15:46.684  1187: 1221 D/         ]
                                           HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xb70d02c0, tid 1221
```

> 08-07 16:15:50.397 1197-1324/? E/AudioFlinger: no wake lock to update!
>   08-07 16:15:50.400 1197-1197/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input
>   stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000 08-07
>   16:15:50.514 1197-1197/? E/AudioFlinger: int
>   android::load_audio_interface(const char*, audio_hw_device_t**)
>   couldn't load audio hw module audio.r_submix (No such file or
>   directory) 08-07 16:15:50.566 1197-1197/? E/SoundTriggerHwService:
>   couldn't load sound trigger module sound_trigger.primary (No such file
>   or directory) 08-07 16:15:50.607 1197-1197/? E/RadioService: couldn't
>   load radio module radio.primary (No such file or directory) 08-07
>   16:16:34.734 1193-1193/? E/Netd: exec() res=0, status=768 for
>   /system/bin/iptables -w -t nat -N oem_nat_pre  08-07 16:16:35.220
>   1193-1193/? E/Netd: exec() res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables
>   -w -t nat -A PREROUTING -j oem_nat_pre  08-07 16:16:35.459 1200-1200/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
>   08-07 16:16:35.491 1200-1200/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load
>   memtrack module: -2 08-07 16:16:37.310 1193-1193/? E/Netd: exec()
>   res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -w -t nat -N
>   natctrl_nat_POSTROUTING  08-07 16:16:37.701 1193-1193/? E/Netd: exec()
>   res=0, status=768 for /system/bin/iptables -w -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j
>   natctrl_nat_POSTROUTING  08-07 16:16:48.729 1200-1200/? E/Minikin:
>   addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/NanumGothic.ttf 08-07
>   16:16:48.730 1200-1200/? E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font
>   /system/fonts/DroidSansFallback.ttf 08-07 16:16:48.730 1200-1200/?
>   E/Minikin: addFont failed to create font /system/fonts/MTLmr3m.ttf
>   08-07 16:17:06.251 1193-1193/? E/Netd: cannot find interface dummy0
>   08-07 16:17:08.653 1200-1200/? E/EmojiFactory_jni: Failed to load
>   libemoji.so: dlopen failed: library "libemoji.so" not found 08-07
>   16:18:44.164 1200-1200/? E/libEGL:
>   load_driver(/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so): dlopen failed:
>   library "/system/lib/egl/libGLES_emulation.so" not found 08-07
>   16:18:44.919 1200-1200/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation
>   /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.pat.txt
>                                                java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-en-us.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No
>   such file or directory)
>                                                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
>                                                    at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.(IoUtils.java:207)
>                                                    at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
>                                                    at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
>                                                    at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
>                                                 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory)
>                                                    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>                                                    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
>                                                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
>                                                    at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.(IoUtils.java:207) 
>                                                    at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114) 
>                                                    at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96) 
>                                                    at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154) 
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)

```
                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186) 
                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)  08-07
```

> 16:18:44.969 1200-1200/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation
>   /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-eu.pat.txt
>                                                java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-eu.pat.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such
>   file or directory)
>                                                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
>                                                    at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.(IoUtils.java:207)
>                                                    at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114)
>                                                    at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96)
>                                                    at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154)
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186)
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
>                                                 Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory)
>                                                    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
>                                                    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
>                                                    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
>                                                    at libcore.io.IoUtils$FileReader.(IoUtils.java:207) 
>                                                    at libcore.io.IoUtils.readFileAsString(IoUtils.java:114) 
>                                                    at android.text.Hyphenator.loadHyphenator(Hyphenator.java:96) 
>                                                    at android.text.Hyphenator.init(Hyphenator.java:154) 
>                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preloadTextResources(ZygoteInit.java:207)

```
                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.preload(ZygoteInit.java:186) 
                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)  08-07
```

> 16:18:45.058 1200-1200/? E/Hyphenator: error loading hyphenation
>   /system/usr/hyphen-data/hyph-hu.pat.txt

Comment: You could try to use Genymotion. If you can't find an answer regarding this error

Answer (score 0):

As `cricket_007` suggested in the comment, it is generally suggested to use Genymotion or something similar since they're so much better.

Apart from that, if you're keen on running the emulator that comes with AS, you might also want to get Intel HAXM (Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager) driver from Android Package Manager. It provides hardware acceleration, but the benefits vary device to device.